# My sessions are used once after i post them, then they no longer work in IE only

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I have been working on my website in Chrome and I decided to open it in IE to see how it looked and it was great except for one thing. All of my sessions would work one time and then the next time they were to be called, they didnt work. In Chrome it would carry the session across a few pages as I needed it, but IE only uses the session once.

Page 1

```
<form action="step2" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="2" /> 2 Cars <input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="3" /> 3 Cars    <input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="4" /> 4 Cars    <input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="5" checked/> 5 Cars
</form>
```

Next Page (it works on this page)

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php $_SESSION['NumberOfCars']=$_POST['NumberOfCars'];?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['NumberOfCars'];?>
```

Third Page (does NOT work here)

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['NumberOfCars'];?>
```

I have a lot more variables that I am doing on each page, this is jsut an example of of one. all of them have the same problem. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Try increasing the session timeout using ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',9999); I had also face such issue but this resolved it.

Comment: where do I put that? is that java?

Comment: no man its just to setup php configuration. you can put these code in common.php file that is included throughout your site. or simple create php.ini file in root of your project and write session.gc_maxlifetime=9999;

Comment: How are you visiting the page? Cookies are [case sensitive to path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#109126) even in IE.

Comment: using a submit button within the form. On the first page it is <form action="step2" method="post"> and on the second it is <form action="step3" method="post">. but it fails to pass it more than one time. I trid the max life thing and it didnt work